# How do I get a "show password" effect in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, passwords

I am making an email login program in visual basic 2015 with various options, one of them being the option to show password or not with probably a check box. It is just a simple, standard windows forms application, I am relatively new to it.

Edit: Answered by jmcilhinney. Thanks! :D

```
Private Sub CheckBox1_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles CheckBox1.CheckedChanged

'Display plain text if and only if check box is checked.

TextBox1.UseSystemPasswordChar = Not CheckBox1.Checked

End Sub
```

Comment: simply change the `UseSystemPasswordChar` property of the password textbox to false  on checkbox checkedchanged event.

Answer (score 3):

Set the `UseSystemPasswordChar` property of your `TextBox` to `True` to mask the password.

```
Private Sub CheckBox1_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles CheckBox1.CheckedChanged
    'Display plain text if and only if check box is checked.
    TextBox1.UseSystemPasswordChar = Not CheckBox1.Checked
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Private Sub txtPassword_MouseHover(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles txtPassword.MouseHover
    txtPassword.PasswordChar = ""
End Sub

Private Sub txtPassword_MouseLeave(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles txtPassword.MouseLeave
    txtPassword.PasswordChar = "*"
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to do couple of changes. Change your password textbox `UseSystemPasswordChar` to false and the `PasswordChar` to `Char(0)`. Something like this:

```
If chkViewPassword.Checked Then txbPwd.PasswordChar = Convert.ToChar(0) Else txbPwd.PasswordChar = Convert.ToChar("*")
    txbSMTPPwd.UseSystemPasswordChar = Not chkViewPassword.Checked
```